# how to retrieve and sum up values of multiple checkboxes?

Tags: android, android-activity, checkbox

```
if(checkbox1.isChecked())
{
   String text=checkbox1.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: please provide more information what exactly you want so anyone can help you.

Comment: Yes, @AndyDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

For all of your checkboxes use :

```
if(checkbox1.isChecked && checkbox2.isChecked)
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

For one of checkboxes:

```
if(checkbox1.isChecked || checkbox2.isChecked)
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```